# DerbyJS Find Record from collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, derbyjs

I wand to get record from collection

```
var query=model.query('sales.dept',{price:100});
model.subscribe(query,function(err,bun)
{
       var data= query.ref('+page.sales').get();
         //its return empty array
          console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be `query.ref('+page.sales')`, you probably want something like `query.ref('_page.sales')` instead.

Try the following, and make sure that you have added data to the collection.

```
var query = model.query('sales.dept',{price:100});
query.subscribe(function(err) {
   query.ref('_page.sales');
   console.log('Data', query.get());
});
```